# Tooltips hidden/inactivated by SphericalPlot3D

Tags: plotting, interactive, tooltip

Any way to get points obscured by SphericalPlot3D to show their Tooltip?

In the below example, Tooltips will appear when cursor moves over little spheres that are not obscured by the plot, but will not appear for spheres behind or within the SphericalPlot3D surface.

```
ttPoints = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {15, 3}];
Show[
 Graphics3D[Tooltip[Sphere[2 #, .1], #] & /@ ttPoints]

, SphericalPlot3D[
  1.5 + .1 Sin[5 ϕ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}
  , Mesh -> None
  , PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25]
  , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
  ]
]
```

[image: Plotted Surface and small spheres]

Comment: I'm using Version 12.0.0. on MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: you need to provide an `Epilog` to override the 3D graphic, I believe. There is a post about geoplot and some city markings on a globe. I think that is what you want to do to overcome this!

Comment: does `Show[SphericalPlot3D[
  1.5 + .1 Sin[5 \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], 
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[ #, .1] & /@ ttPoints, 
   Tooltip[Text["", #], #] & /@ ttPoints}], ImageSize -> 400]` work in your version/os?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove `Tooltip` from `Sphere`s and
2. Add `Tooltip`ped `Text` objects with the same coordinates using 
   `Tooltip[Text["", #], #] & /@ ttPoints`

```
SeedRandom[1]
ttPoints = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {15, 3}]; 
Show[ SphericalPlot3D[1.5 + .1 Sin[5 ϕ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], 
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[#, .1] & /@ ttPoints, 
   Tooltip[Text["", #], #] & /@ ttPoints}]]
```

[image]

**Note:** This  approach works in version 9 (Windows 64 bit). Cannot check if it works in later versions.

**Note:** Modified OP's example so that all spheres fall inside the spherical plot surface.

Comment: Thanks. Works fine on Version 12.0.0. on MacOS 10.13.6.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach:

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

SeedRandom[1234];
ttPoints = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {15, 3}] // Sort;

Manipulate[
 Column[{Show[
    Graphics3D[
     Transpose[
      {ReplacePart[
        ConstantArray[LightBlue, Length[ttPoints]],
        pt -> Red],
       Tooltip[Sphere[2 #, .1], #] & /@ ttPoints}]],
    SphericalPlot3D[1.5 + .1 Sin[5 ϕ],
     {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi},
     Mesh -> None,
     PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25],
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}],
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   ttPoints[[pt]]}],
 {{pt, 1, Point},
  Thread[Range[Length[ttPoints]] ->
    (NumberForm[#, {4, 1}] & /@ ttPoints)],
  ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: We could also do the same sort-of work around with an application of `Epilog`, no? It should, then, be possible to roll over the smaller spheres, and have the `Tooltips` appear in a single designated space!