# Tooltip pointing for 3D polyhedron vertices

Tags: graphics3d

How is possible to use Tooltip to point out vertices of a polyhedron? Would like coordinate display while mousing over the vertex. Thanks for the help.

```
Rohn = PolyhedronData["Icosidodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"];
DelaunayMesh[Rohn]
Show[ListPlot3D[Rohn, AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Corr(X,Y)"}, 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}], 
 ListPointPlot3D@
  Tooltip@Flatten[MapIndexed[Flatten@{#2, #1} &, Rohn, {2}], 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198918/125) to a related question:

```
g3d = PolyhedronData["Icosidodecahedron"]; 
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Opacity[.7]], g3d[[1]], {Sphere[#, .1] & /@ Rohn, 
   Tooltip[Text["", #], #] & /@ ToRadicals[Rohn]}}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005], AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Corr(X,Y)"}, 
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
MeshRegion[DelaunayMesh[Rohn], MeshCellLabel ->
  MapIndexed[Prepend[#2, 0] -> Placed[{#1}, Tooltip] &, Rohn]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot. Point update at places is slower however. Maybe thicker edge choice needed?

Comment: What do you mean by "point update"? For thicker edges I would add ```MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Thick}``` to MeshRegion.